# 2-Legged Client Credentials OAuth Flow for Exchange/O365 POP3 and SMTP

Tags: email, azure-active-directory, office365, exchange-server, pop3

My company distributes an application with a background service component that sends and receives mail from a single email account using SMTP/POP3.

The app uses basic authentication, but we need to implement OAuth 2.0 now due to Microsoft's planned rollback of basic auth for POP3 (and likely SMTP in the future). We have been investigating the account setup and API permissions necessary to achieve this in Azure AD.

Our current understanding is that it is possible to implement the 2-legged client credentials flow by getting an access token and then sending requests to the Graph API (eg. https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.ReadWrite). However, our application is built to send and receive with the legacy SMTP/POP3 protocols and changing the mail features to send HTTP requests to the Microsoft API endpoints requires a partial redesign.

It appears that only 3-legged flows are supported for the legacy SMTP and POP protocols. These permissions are only available as "delegated permissions" on the Graph API. There are no equivalent "application permissions" that would allow us to use these protocols from our background service without a user present to do the initial authentication.

Integrating a browser redirect into the app for the initial authentication also requires a significant update to the application. The app is 14 years old and the original programmer is no longer at the company. Due to that fact as well as limited resources, we're hoping for a solution that doesn't involve implementing browser integration or major changes to the sending and receiving functions.

Is it possible to implement a 2-legged OAuth flow to authenticate an account for sending and receiving over SMTP/POP3?

Might any of our assumptions be incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It's impossible.

OAuth access to IMAP, POP, SMTP AUTH protocols via **OAuth2 client credentials grant flow** is not supported.

Currently the supported flows are:

1. OAuth2 authorization code flow
2. OAuth2 Device authorization grant flow

See details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth#get-an-access-token).

If you have this requirement, you can post your idea on [Microsoft Graph user voice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests).

Comment: Client credentials is now planned for IMAP and POP: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=70577
You can vote for SMTP here: https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/40638931-add-support-for-imap-pop-smtp-auth-protocols-via

Comment: @imclean I could able to access mailbox using IMAP and client credentials flow but fails with SMTP + client credentials flow. Is it still not supported ? If yes, then can be redirect me to any documentation which states that SMTP + client credentials flow is not supported.

Comment: BTW @imclean both URLs mentioned in your comment is looks like broken..

Comment: @Amogh - Microsoft likes to change things around to keep us on our toes. Uservoice has been discontinued and all its feature requests closed.  A simple search will show you client credentials flow is not available for SMTP yet.  See comments:  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/announcing-oauth-2-0-client-credentials-flow-support-for-pop-and/bc-p/3730727/highlight/true#M35397

Comment: Also see:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth#use-client-credentials-grant-flow-to-authenticate-imap-and-pop-connections